# What is the gradle implementation for CameraSource CameraSourcePreview GraphicOverlay

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

I'm using google bardcode scanner and after recreating their sample, these three classes are missing and I couldn't find anywhere mentioning them

ps: they seem to work fine in the original sample.

Comment: also, they seem to work fine in the original sample

Comment: please edit your question if you want to add something to it, instead of commenting on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're not library of any sort, they're just simple classes written inside the Project you've downloaded.
you need to copy/paste them in your own project.

Comment: thank you for quick answer, it works after copying them from the sample project.

Comment: I've another problem, BarcodeGraphicTracker is still missing even after adding the classes